# Grouping Users on a virtual roster

Tags: php, mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to come up with the most simple / userful / efficient method to group 3 users together using mysql.

To set the stage:

- X number of users in a list (all with int account_id's)
- mini groupings need to be created on a per user basis (user 1 wants to group with 220 for instance).
- Max 3 people per grouping (user 1 + user 220 + user 9123 = group full)
- Need to easily find if a user is in a group or not without looking in a bunch of columns

I'm stumped about how best to create a schema for this (so I can easily query my table to see if user is in a group, or if they can be added, or check for group space availability).

Anyone have any idea?  My initial thought is schema like this (but it really seems too rigid):

**Schema**

```
GROUP_ID  USER1  USER2  USER3 LASTUPDATE
1         1      220    null  5/25/2011 20:00:00
2         300    2      4     5/25/2011 20:00:00
```

How would you do it to make something this simple very flexible and efficient. I really feel stupid for asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I would approach this by using 3 tables.

```
Users Table
user_id user_name ..... last_update

Groups Table
group_id group_name ......

Users to groups Table
user_to_group_id user_id group_id
```

This forms a many to many relationship by linking through the ***"Users to groups"*** table, obviously you can have more that 3 users linked to one group so you will have to make your PHP logic check for this when adding a new user to a group.

You can simply use SQL joins to retrieve all the data required and filter the results in your PHP code.

I hope this helps

Kind regards

Garry

Comment: In the 3rd (associative) table, the primary key can also be the composite `(user_id, group_id)`.